# Are inseparable elements of an extension field closed under addition?

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, separable-extension

I know that both the separable and purely inseparable elements form fields. It seems very likely false that the inseparable elements form a field, but in a proof I'm developing the following fact would be very useful:

> Inseparable elements of an extension field are closed under addition.

Is it true? Could it be true in some special cases, if not in general (e.g. in finite extensions)?